# Where can I find my K/D and kill-streak stats in Battlefield 1?

Tags: battlefield-1

I can't find my K/D ratio or my highest kill-streak in the soldiers tab in the menu. Anyone find it already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can only view it online, not in-game. See [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/190144-battlefield-1/74233312):

> You can access the current test version at the following address. (EA login required)
>
> https://www.battlefield.com/companion/career
>
> You can view your stats from BF1 and BF4, see your kills per weapon/vehicle, edit your infantry/vehicle loadouts and check your progress on medal assignments.

Comment: Yeah i know, have to wait for 3 minutes before i can mark your answers for some reason.

Comment: @Babidi There's a 15 minute period after a question has been asked that answers cannot be accepted during.

Comment: Seems a bit weird to have to go outside of a videogame to view content of said videogame.

Comment: This no longer works, https://www.battlefield.com/career is 404, it's been replaced with https://www.battlefield.com/companion/career

Comment: @vartec I was going to edit it but you beat me to it :P thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to [BF1Stats.com](http://bf1stats.com)

I've been using this site for years.  It helps with tracking unlockables, rank, scores, etc.  Very in depth site.

[image: BF1 Stats1]
[image: BF1 Stats2]
[image: BF1 Stats3]
[image: BF1 Stats4]

Now keep in mind I don't play very much of BF1, but I have been using this site since BF3.  At the top of the page where it says "P-Stats Network", you can switch games and look at those too.  Honestly, this site is much better than anything EA can put out.  The only things it can't do is change your loadouts, skins, and choose a server.  If you're looking for straight stats and stats only, this is the site you go it.